# What is the difference between "find out" and "discover"?

Tags: phrases

I do not know how to use the expression **find out**, I had read that I need to use instead **discover**, but it does not mean always.

For example, what is the best example?

I *found out* that she is single

or

I *discovered* that she is single

Comment: If you *I found **out** [some fact was true]*, that tends to imply you made some effort to obtain the information - in contrast to *I found [it was true]*, which is more likely in contexts where the information came to you by happenstance (cf *ferret **out**, turn **out***.) To *discover* something implies nothing one way or the other in that respect (and you *can't* add a preposition to "nudge" the meaning towards either possibility).

Comment: Actually I was thinking that *found out* can be very much a passive thing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your example, you can use either. I would say *find out* is a bit less formal.

There is a difference in meaning though, and in some cases the words are not interchangeable. You can only *find out* a fact, but you can *discover* anything that can be perceived.

For example:

> I found out that I'm pregnant.
>
> Did you find out whether it's going to rain tomorrow?
>
> I discovered a $20 bill under a rock.
>
> I discovered confidence in myself that I never thought I had.

There is a slightly different usage in *to be found out*, an idiomatic expression meaning *to be exposed or caught*.

Answer (score 4):

**Find** derives from proto-Germanic languages, and its original form was *finthan*, which means "to come upon, discover". **Find out** is an expression that came from Middle English *outfinden* which means "to discover by scrutiny" (discover by deep analysis). ([source](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=find))

**Discover** is a word derived from Latin *dis*- "opposite of" + *cooperire* "to cover up". Once it had a sense of betrayal or malicious exposure, but nowadays, since the 1550s, it means "to obtain knowledge or sight of what was not known". ([source](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=discover))

Both words/expressions are equivalent in meaning, but in a casual speech, it's much more likely to hear *find out* than *discover*, since the latter has Latin origins, which can be classified as "fancy word", used mainly in Courts of Justice or in formal conversations with authorities.

Answer (score 2):

**Find out** implies what you were looking for is already known or exists.
**Discover** implies finding something new.

> You can **find out** about things that have been already **discovered**.
> Once you **discover** *something*, you can **find out** more about it through research.

Comment: Short, succinct, yet clear enough! +1

Comment: You can discover something that is new to you, even if others knew about it already. For instance, I might go down to the brewery and discover a new beer I like.

Comment: And we can presume how you **find out** more about it! :)

Answer (score -1):

I think find out is use when there is a definite thing to look; while discover is finding something without definitely looking for it or it may be finding something accidentally or incidentally.
example: The police will find out the thief.
         Magellan discovered(or rediscovered)the Philippines while on his way to find the Spice Island.